# Save PLC EasyModbus data

Tags: python, postgresql

I need to save data from a PLC to a PostgreSQL database for which I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
Created on 12.09.2016
@author: Stefan Rossmann
'''
# @UnresolvedImport
from easymodbus.modbusClient import *
# @UnresolvedImport
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="127.0.0.1",
                        port="5432",
                        user="americo",
                        password="123456",
                        database="rapidscada")
modbusClient = ModbusClient('192.168.5.1', 502)
#modbusClient = ModbusClient('COM4')
modbusClient.connect()
#discreteInputs = modbusClient.read_discreteinputs(3, 1)
holding_registers = modbusClient.read_holdingregisters(3, 1)
print (holding_registers)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mitablita (datito, detalle) VALUES(%s, %s)", (holding_registers, 'tg1010_2'))
conn.commit() # <- We MUST commit to reflect the inserted data
cursor.close()
conn.close()
modbusClient.close()
```

It gives me data type error. This is strange because the data to save and the table field are both integers.

Comment: WHERE do you get the error?  Which line?  Show is the complete traceback.

Comment: Also remember that `read_holdingregisters` returns a LIST of values, even if the list only has 1 value.  You need to write `holding_registers[0]` to get the first value.